# After getting user input "Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);" how to use is in a if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner, system.in

So im learning java,bit by bit im getting a bit more knowledge, now im following tutroials and other webistes ect on learning but im stuck on one problem where i can't figure out what's the problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class apples{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.print("Player Name?");
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(name.nextLine());

        System.out.print(" ,how old are you?");
        Scanner age = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(age.nextLine());



        if (age >= 15){
            System.out.println("welcome to Azura World");
        }else{
            System.out.println("insufficient experience");
        }
    }
}
```

from what this should do is,ask the player name, one i type that it should ask name, how old are you? with that at hand, i have the age of the input, there for i want to use it in a if statement but its not working i don't understand why. so please explain if have time.

Also im using [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28) as a guide for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because java is statically-typed and `Scanner`'s `readLine` method returns a String, A `String` is not an `int` or an `Integer` and as such cannot be compared with an `int` or an `Integer`. You need to 'cast' the returned value to an `Integer` to be able to compare it with an int, using either Paras Mittal or suchit solutions (I'd personnaly go for Paras solution as it uses native `Scanner` functionality).

This adds some difficulties, because you now have to handle the case where the user didn't provide you with an '`Integer`-like' answer (As you would ultimately have to with your actual code, it just doesn't show up for now). In such case, readLine will throw an `InputMismatchException` which you have at least two ways to deal with (there may be more depending on your imagination):

1. because it inherits `RuntimeException`, you could just ignore it and let it blow at your user, or whoever is the consumer of your method
2. you can surround `age.nextInt();` with a `try...catch` clause and then do whatever is significant to your use case (ignore it and set clever default for that value, ask again to the user), You could also preemptively test that user input can be cast into an Integer or keep asking.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are simply printing the value, first store it in some variable then compare:

```
String userage = age.nextLine();
int a=Integer.valueOf(userage);
 if (a >= 15){
        System.out.println("welcome to Azura World");
    }else{
        System.out.println("insufficient experience");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Player Name?");
    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(name.nextLine());

    System.out.print(" ,how old are you?");
    Scanner age = new Scanner(System.in);

    int ageVal = age.nextInt();

    System.out.print(ageVal);

    if (ageVal >= 15){
        System.out.println("welcome to Azura World");
    }else{
        System.out.println("insufficient experience");
    }
}
```